# Running one command at a time in a shell script

Tags: shell, zsh

I am using Mac OS and zsh. I am running a shell script that launches several Java programs. They terminate once they have created their output (they are essentially scripts). However, it seems that my current script starts all the Java programs at once, which is very resource-intensive.

Currently my shell script looks like this:

```
java -Xmx2048M -jar gha.jar params1.yaml
java -Xmx2048M -jar gha.jar params2.yaml
java -Xmx2048M -jar gha.jar params3.yaml
```

When I run it, I run out of memory. How can I modify my script so that it only launches the next Java program once the first one has terminated, so that memory is refreshed in between?

Comment: Are you sure all programs start running at once? Maybe they are daemonized when started?

Comment: Could be the case. I wouldn't know what daemonized means. All I know is that if I run the command `top` I see a whole bunch of Java processes, and then my program crashes halfway through the Java "scripts"

Comment: If the parent process spawns a child process and exits, the shell will continue the execution of the script. This may be the case. Or maybe a lot of processes are spawned and you're out of memory at the first step already.

Comment: No, I run out of memory only halfway through. In total I launch 18 Java processes, and I run out of memory on the 10th process. If I split the script in two, then I'm fine memorywise. But I'd still like to solve the problem in principle.

Comment: You could monitor the output of `top` or `ps` in your script.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken. The shell will run these one-at-a-time. The only possible explanation is if these programs launch background processes, in which case the shell cannot know how to wait for them to complete.

Answer (score 1):

As @bmargulies mentioned above your command as you have show it should run one command at a time.

Try modifying your shell script as as shown below. Using the construction below a command is run only if the previous command completes successfully (in theory at least).

```
java -Xmx2048M -jar gha.jar params1.yaml && java -Xmx2048M -jar gha.jar params2.yaml && java -Xmx2048M -jar gha.jar params3.yaml
```

If this does not work, run the script in the background and list out the currently running processes.  Hopefully that'll give you an idea of what's running on your system.